# Reset work node when to rejoin to master using kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

When I drain and remove existing work node in cluster, if I want to rejoin it to master, it report a error under below.

```
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred: 
  [ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-kubelet.conf]: /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf already exists
  [ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-pki-ca.crt]: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt already exists
```

Answer (score 6):

It is happening because you've already executed **join** command on your node once. That's why the files are still there.

If your node hasn't been deleted from the cluster(just drained only), you don't have to run **kubeadm join**. You can rejoin the node by running the command-

```
kubectl uncordon NODENAME
```

Else, to get rid of this error, try running the following command on your node to purge these files-

```
kubeadm reset
```

If the reset command fails, try forcing the reset process by running-

```
kubeadm reset --force
```

Now try to execute the **join** command again.